# How to show complete column as editable in extjs grid(cell editing)?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I am using cell editing plugin for editing a cell. But it is like when we click that colunm it will move to edit mode. I want to show complete column with editable text box.

Currently I am using following code to make it editable.

```
selType: 'cellmodel',
plugins: [
   Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
      clicksToEdit: 1
   })
],


columns: [
    { text: ... },
    { text: ... },
    { text: ... },
    { text: 'TText', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'TText',
        editor: {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            allowBlank: false
        }
    }

]
```

Comment: Do you mean you want all rows of a column to be in editable mode?

Comment: yes. all rows of a column in editable mode

Comment: we style a black border around the cells in the column, would that be sufficient for your needs?  I can show you how we did it

Comment: @Reimius I think that is a good option, could you show that solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this will work good enough for your scenario:

```
columns: [
    { text: ... },
    { text: ... },
    { text: ... },
    { text: 'TText', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'TText',
        editor: {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            allowBlank: false
        },
        renderer: function(value, metaData){
            metaData.style = "border: 1px gray solid;";
            return value;
        }
    }

]
```

Answer (score 0):

Wait for the `beforeedit` event and then

```
... Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
              clicksToEdit: 1,
              listeners: {
                 beforeedit: function( oEditor, oOptions ) {

// for each record start the edit mode 'startEdit()' 
   } 
}
```

Check the doc: [startEdit()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing-method-startEdit)

Comment: 'startEdit()'  is asking for object. But i could not understand what object it wants. I put a debugger inside beforeedit function. but it is hitting only when i click the row. I need each row of column should show as editable when loading the grid itself. thanks